# identify version from a string using php regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the version number for some string in php. Here is the sample code

```
<?php

    function getVersion($str) {
        preg_match("/.*((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)/i", $str, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }

    print_r(getVersion("ansitl1-isam-6.0 1.0 9.7.03 418614 +"));
    print_r(getVersion("ams-ef 9.6.06ef4 - 394867"));

?>
```

for input string `ansitl1-isam-6.0 1.0 9.7.03 418614 +` output should be 9.7.03
for input string `ams-ef 9.6.06ef4 - 394867` output should be 9.6.06

How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please let us know what you tried and what didn't worked?

Comment: I tried the below function getVersion($str) {
    preg_match("/.*((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)/i", $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

Comment: For pattern num.num.num preceded by a space try [`(?<= )\d+\.\d+\.\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/Engs6D/1)

Comment: @bobble bubble Do we need to provide escape characters? I am getting error Unknown modifier '\\'

Comment: Oh you're using double quotes. Either use single quotes for pattern or double the backslash :) [See this PHP demo](https://tio.run/##TY3PC4IwHMXv@yu@SOCGOR2JFRpeO3rqkhHD5g/QKds8RX/7WkHS4T0eH97jzd1sbV6U5xKhZpG16ScJrTAXobSLeKONIvBEAH2DZyXa@8hN3WE/wkV@AlI9gor@LPK38Bk4/7aEJsQtAZQwi5Irvca3DK204YMWGXohJOpu@j/3uNS9GVjYaz6GKY2BOR3pnsY7SNghZQkEHsmsfQM)

Comment: @bobble bubble . it worked. thanks

Comment: @Nawaz I put it as an answer, glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is always *num.num.num* preceded by a space.

```
(?<= )\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

See [this demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Engs6D/1) or a [PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY3PC4IwHMXv@yu@SOCGOR2JFRpeO3rqkhHD5g/QKds8RX/7WkHS4T0eH97jzd1sbV6U5xKhZpG16ScJrTAXobSLeKONIvBEAH2DZyXa@8hN3WE/wkV@AlI9gor@LPK38Bk4/7aEJsQtAZQwi5Irvca3DK204YMWGXohJOpu@j/3uNS9GVjYaz6GKY2BOR3pnsY7SNghZQkEHsmsfQM)

There is not much Regex magic used here, just a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check, there is a space before.
Instead it can also be done by a [caturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and getting `$out[1]` [like in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Engs6D/2).